# Adding data to existing array after using array data

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of data that is being created from a MySQL query which I am then using to create more data which I then need back in the array (or a new one) but I haven't been able to get this working at all.

Here is the code I have been trying to use:

```
$vars['items'] = $this->_query('SELECT customers.*, sites.site_name as `default_location` 
                                FROM `customers` 
                                JOIN `sites` ON customers.site_id=sites.id');

$a=array();

foreach($vars['items'] as $customer)
{
    if($customer['record_to_use'] == '2')
    {
        $results = dns_get_record($customer['cust_mx'], DNS_MX);
        $mx = min(array_column($results, "pri"));
        $highest = array_filter(
            $results,
            function($item) use($mx) {return $item["pri"] === $mx;}
        );
        foreach ($highest as $mx)
        {
            $results = dns_get_record($mx["target"], DNS_A);
            foreach ($results as $a)
            {
                $vars['items']['ip'] .= $a['ip'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I need the IP that gets created from each item in the array to get added into that array as `$vars['items']['ip']`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Currently, what you are getting?

Comment: @TamilvananN - I have omitted the real data but here is the array with the changed line $vars['items']['ip'][] = $a['ip'];

array(2) { [0]=> array(8) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["cust_name"]=> string(11) "ITEM" ["cust_a"]=> string(0) "" ["cust_mx"]=> string(35) "ITEM" ["record_to_use"]=> string(1) "2" ["site_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["added_by"]=> string(1) "1" ["default_location"]=> string(9) "ITEM" } ["ip"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "x.x.x.x"  } }

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($results as $a => $value)
                        {
                            $vars['items'][$a]['ip'] = $value['ip'];
                        }
```

That's what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$vars['items']['ip'] .= $a['ip'];
```

`.=` is concatenation if that was a typo in your code.

Try `$vars['items']['ip'] = $a['ip'];`

Comment: This doesn't work. that creates a second single array and just adds one item to the end of the other arrary: 

["ip"]=> string(13) "x.x.x.x" }

That single entry is added after the array and not with each item in the array

Comment: @PeteWall If you want to store it on the array then try `$vars['items']['ip'][] = $a['ip'];`

Comment: This adds an IP for each entry into a seperate array at the end. $items['vars'] currently is 8 keys per row in the database. I want to turn that into 9 adding the IP for each row.